# Jetpack Compose Focus Order with Talkback

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Following the doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).focusOrder(kotlin.Function1)

I want to have a custom focus order for a `Column`.

I've followed the doc and set different focus requesters to each item and specified the item to focus `next`, but it seems Talkback is ignoring the focus order of my elements.

Here's an example:

```
                val focusRequesters = remember { List(4) { FocusRequester() } }
                Column {
                    Text("Line 1",
                        Modifier
                            .focusOrder(focusRequesters[0]) {
                                next = focusRequesters[2]
                                down = focusRequesters[2]
                                right = focusRequesters[2]
                            }
                            .focusable())
                    Text("Line 2",
                        Modifier
                            .focusOrder(focusRequesters[1]) {
                                next = focusRequesters[0]
                                down = focusRequesters[0]
                                right = focusRequesters[0]
                            }
                            .focusable())
                    Text("Line 3",
                        Modifier
                            .focusOrder(focusRequesters[2]) {
                                next = focusRequesters[3]
                                down = focusRequesters[3]
                                right = focusRequesters[3]
                            }
                            .focusable())
                    Text("Line 4",
                        Modifier
                            .focusOrder(focusRequesters[3]) {
                                next = focusRequesters[1]
                                down = focusRequesters[1]
                                right = focusRequesters[1]
                            }
                            .focusable())
                }
```

Tried a combination of `next`, `down`, `right` and each alone but nothing seems to change the Accessibility traversal order.

Answer (score 3):

The order of focus order will be taken into account if you change it with `LocalFocusManager`, something like this:

```
LocalFocusManager.current.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
```

But it has nothing to do with accessibility. It seems that the `android:accessibilityTraversalAfter` counterpart is not yet available in Compose, follow [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186443263) for details.

Comment: It's actually changing to not confuse the user, as sometimes the natural order doesn't make sense. You can already do this with `View` using `android:accessibilityTraversalAfter` and `Before`. With `LocalFocusManager` it seems you need a keyboard action/options to trigger the `Nexd` event, but they don't respond to talkback 'Next' events